# How to check if element contains specific class attribute

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I check if a selenium web element contains a specific css class.

I have this html li element

```
<li class="list-group-item ng-scope active" ng-repeat="report in lineageController.reports" ng-click="lineageController.activate(report)" ng-class="{active : lineageController.active == report}">
```

As you can see inside class attribute there is an active class.

My problem is that I have this element and I want to do a check based on if the class attribute has that "active" value among the others, being more elegant solution then using xpath.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Given you already found your element and you want to check for a certain class inside the class-attribute:

```
public boolean hasClass(WebElement element) {
    String classes = element.getAttribute("class");
    for (String c : classes.split(" ")) {
        if (c.equals(theClassYouAreSearching)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

#EDIT
As @aurelius rightly pointed out, there is an even simpler way (that doesn't work very well):

```
public boolean elementHasClass(WebElement element, String active) {
    return element.getAttribute("class").contains(active);
}
```

This approach looks simpler but has one big caveat:

As pointed out by @JuanMendes you will run into problems if the class-name you're searching for is a substring of other class-names:

> for example class="test-a test-b", searching for class.contains("test") will return true but it should be false

#EDIT 2
Try combining the two code snippets:

```
public boolean elementHasClass(WebElement element, String active) {
    return Arrays.asList(element.getAttribute("class").split(" ")).contains(active);
}
```

That should fix your caveat.

Comment: classes.contains("active") is enough, thanks for this!

Comment: -1 because the edit is not good enough, it will give you false positives if you search for a substring of a class, for example `class="test-a test-b"`, searching for `class.contains("test")` will return true but it should be false

Comment: it depends on the case, variations of css class names. If you know the a certain class name will not have these name clashes, it works just fine.

Comment: instead of "contains", how about using `.getAttribute("class").matches("^classname | classname | classname$")`? That should fix the issue of name subsets.

Comment: correction: it should of course be `.getAttribute("class").matches("^classname .*|.* classname .*|.* classname$|^classname$")`

Comment: @drkthng the `elementHasClass` method is suuuuuuper redundant.

Comment: Edit 2 does not have valid code.  The split method returns a string array which does not have the contains method.  In order to perform that you will need to first convert the array to a list.

Comment: EDIT 2 should be like:
public boolean elementHasClass(WebElement element, String active) {
    return element.getAttribute("class").contains(active);
}

Answer (score 10):

The answer provided by @drkthng works but you might have a case where the class name is a subset of another class name. For example:

```
<li class="list-group-item ng-scope active">text</li>
```

If you wanted to find the class "item" then the provided answer would give a false positive. You might want to try something like this:

```
public boolean hasClass(WebElement element, String htmlClass) {
    String classes = element.getAttribute("class").split("\\s+");
    if (classes != null) {
        for (String classAttr: classes) {
            if (classAttr.equals(htmlClass)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use javascript: classList.contains

```
 WebElement element = By.id("id");
 String className = "hidden";
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 Boolean containsClass = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].classList.contains(arguments[1])", element, className);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on a common pre-`classList` javascript technique:

```
public boolean hasClass(WebElement element, String theClass) {
    return (" " + element.getAttribute("class") + " ").contains(" " + theClass + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simmilar to previous one, but with java 8 capabilities:

```
String classes= getDriver().findElement(someSelector).getAttribute("class");
Optional<String> classFindResult = Arrays.stream(elementClasses.split(" ")).filter(el -> el.equals("myClass")).findFirst();
if(openClassFindResult.isPresent()){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: classFindResult should be checked not openClassFindResult, and would be a bit more elegant to use the ternary operator. Anyways, you already have my upvote.

Comment: I think you can use `anyMatch()` method instead of doing filtering and then checking if any exists.
`Arrays.stream(elementClasses.split(" ")).anyMatch(css -> css.equals("myClass"));`

Answer (score 2):

Improving on @uesports135 answer, "classess" should be a String array.

```
 public boolean hasClass(WebElement element, String htmlClass) {
        String[] classes = element.getAttribute("class").split("\\s+");
        if (classes != null) {
            for (String classAttr: classes) {
                if (classAttr.equals(htmlClass)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a C# implementation:

```
public static class WebElementExtensions
{
    private static Regex _classNameValidatorRegex = new Regex(@"^[a-z][a-z0-9\-_]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static Regex _whiteSpaceRegex = new Regex(@"\s+");

    public static bool HasClass(this IWebElement element, params string[] htmlClasses)
    {
        if (!htmlClasses.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("No html classes to match.");

        if (!htmlClasses.All(c => _classNameValidatorRegex.IsMatch(c)))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid CSS class(es) detected.");

        var classAttribute = element.GetAttribute("class");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(classAttribute))
            return false;

        var elementClasses = _whiteSpaceRegex.Split(classAttribute.Trim()).ToHashSet();

        return htmlClasses.All(c => elementClasses.Contains(c));
    }

    public static bool HasAnyClass(this IWebElement element, params string[] htmlClasses)
    {
        if (!htmlClasses.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("No html classes to match.");

        if (!htmlClasses.All(c => _classNameValidatorRegex.IsMatch(c)))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid CSS class(es) detected.");

        var classAttribute = element.GetAttribute("class");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(classAttribute))
            return false;

        var elementClasses = _whiteSpaceRegex.Split(classAttribute.Trim()).ToHashSet();

        return htmlClasses.Any(c => elementClasses.Contains(c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using contains();

```
String classes = divPubli.getAttribute("class");
assertTrue("The element does not contain .maClass class .publi",classes.contains("maClass"));
```

Comment: This is not a correct solution- for example it will not fail when you are looking for 'nav' and you have 'nav-item' class.