# How to check if a HTML element contains an other one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if my title `<h3>` has the class `highlight` so I founded [How to check if element contains specific class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713009/how-to-check-if-element-contains-specific-class-attribute) but I'm not sure about how to fit it to my use case because it's not the `<h3>` which contains the class but the span inside it:
[image]

I tried to do this code:

```
$('.liContainer div h3').each(function(i, obj) {
      var contains = false;
      String classes = obj.getAttribute("class");
      for (String c : classes.split(" ")) {
          if (c.equals("highlight")) {
              contains = true;
          }
      }
      if(contains){
        obj.classList.remove("highlight");
      }
    });
```

but I got an error with the actual code:

```
imports/ui/layout.js:42:13: Unexpected token (42:13)
```

and it's the line  `String classes = obj.getAttribute("class");`

Could someone help me to make it works ?
[EDIT] with the help of your answer I'm now here:

```
'click .liContainer div h3': function(e){
       if ( $(e.target).find("span").is(".highlight") ) {
            console.log("it was highlighted");
           $(e.target).find("span").removeClass('highlight');
       }
  },
```

and it works so thank you everybody

Comment: use `.hasClass()`

Comment: @guradio you have an example ?

Comment: `$("#nameMachine h3 span").hasClass("highlight")` will return true if has class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    I hope it will help you

        $('.liContainer div h3').each(function(i, obj) {
           if ( $(this).find("span").is(".highlight") ) {
               // do something
           }
        });

    **can you just help me to do the action only on the clicked h3?**

    If `click` action:

        $('.liContainer div h3').click(function() {
           if ( $(this).find("span").is(".highlight") ) {
               // do something
           }
        });

    I use your code, and change the content of the `each` loop.
    You loop each `<h3>` and check if child `<span>` has class `.highlight`, then you do something...

    The above Code can also be written as follows:

    $('.liContainer div h3').click(function() {
           if ( $(this).find("span.highlight") ) {
               // do something
           }
        });
Hope this works fine.
```

Comment: Maybe I'll use yours finally, can you just help me to do the action only on the clicked `h3` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h3').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('span.highlight').length != 0;
}) // do something with it
```

Answer (score 1):

A rough way to know if you don't know have child selector

`$('#nameMachine *').hasClass('yourClass'); // either true or false`

Comment: Selecting all children might be overkill.

Comment: Yeah, but works if OP only wants to know if class is present somewhere down the DOM

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using `has` selector as given below code :

    $('.liContainer div h3:has(span.highlight)').each(function(){
       // code here
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jquery, how about this simple solution:

```
$('.liContainer div h3 .highlight').removeClass('highlight');
```

Comment: What about using `.hasClass()` ?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey this one remove for all so it do the job, but a good improvement would be to remove the class for the element I click on

Comment: **I want to check if my title <h3> has the class highlight**, what if `.highlight` isn't child of `.liContainer`?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I'll try to it by my own because this answer do the job. But `.highlight` can only be in `.liContainer` (because I coded it like this)

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like:

```
if( $("h3", "#nameMachine").has(".highlight") ) {
// do something 
}
```

Or a more specific version:

```
if( $("> h3", "#nameMachine").has("span.highlight") ) {
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('span.highlight','.liContainer div h3').removeClass('highlight')`

Please note that the second css selector is to determine the scope of searching the first css selector.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` will be searching in all of child element . So if there have wanted class its length will be 1 `else length is 0`.

```
$('.liContainer div h3').each(function(i, obj) {
    var hasClass = $(obj).find(".highlight");            
      if (hasClass.length) {
        hasClass[0].classList.remove("highlight");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do. [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) documentation is here

```
$("#nameMachine h3").hasClass("highlight")
```

Comment: This will select the `h3` he searches for a span containing the class

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($('#parent').find('#child').length) {

 }
```

Comment: Why Downvoting this answer while he provided the correct solution !

Comment: giving a code without explanation isnt an answer at all.. FYI not my down vote @amd